# How to increase the python speed over loops?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, iteration, computation

I have a dataset of 370k records stored in a Pandas Dataframe which needs to be integrated. I tried multiprocessing, threading, Cpython and loop unrolling. But I was not successful and the time shown to compute was 22 hrs. The task is as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline  
from numba import jit, autojit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('data/full_text.txt', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
 strdata=f.readlines()
data=[]

for string in strdata:
 data.append(string.split('\t'))

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["uname","date","UT","lat","long","msg"])

df=df.drop('UT',axis=1)

df[['lat','long']] = df[['lat','long']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

from textblob import TextBlob
from tqdm import tqdm

df['polarity']=np.zeros(len(df))
```

Threading:

```
 from queue import Queue
 from threading import Thread
 import logging
 logging.basicConfig(
 level=logging.DEBUG,
  format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
  )


class DownloadWorker(Thread):
   def __init__(self, queue):
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.queue = queue

   def run(self):
       while True:
           # Get the work from the queue and expand the tuple
         lowIndex, highIndex = self.queue.get()
         a = range(lowIndex,highIndex-1)
         for i in a:
            df['polarity'][i]=TextBlob(df['msg'][i]).sentiment.polarity
         self.queue.task_done()

  def main():
   # Create a queue to communicate with the worker threads
   queue = Queue()
   # Create 8 worker threads
   for x in range(8):
     worker = DownloadWorker(queue)
     worker.daemon = True
     worker.start()
  # Put the tasks into the queue as a tuple
   for i in tqdm(range(0,len(df)-1,62936)):
     logging.debug('Queueing')
     queue.put((i,i+62936 ))
     queue.join()
     print('Took {}'.format(time() - ts))

 main()
```

Multiprocessing with loop unrolling:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
r = pool.map(assign_polarity, df)
pool.close()

def assign_polarity(df):
   a=range(0,len(df),5)
   for i in tqdm(a):
       df['polarity'][i]=TextBlob(df['msg'][i]).sentiment.polarity
       df['polarity'][i+1]=TextBlob(df['msg'][i+1]).sentiment.polarity
       df['polarity'][i+2]=TextBlob(df['msg'][i+2]).sentiment.polarity
       df['polarity'][i+3]=TextBlob(df['msg'][i+3]).sentiment.polarity
       df['polarity'][i+4]=TextBlob(df['msg'][i+4]).sentiment.polarity
```

How to increase the speed of computation? or storing the computation in dataframe in a faster way? My laptop configuration

- Ram: 8GB
- Physical cores: 2
- Logical cores: 8
- Windows 10

Implementing Multiprocessing gave me a higher computation time.
Threading was being executed sequentially (I think because of GIL)
Loop Unrolling gave me the same computation speed. 
Cpython was giving me errors while importing libraries.

Comment: "So I tried multiprocessing, threading, Cpython and loop unrolling." What did not work? Can you post that in the question?

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Boggartfly Thanks, I added the things which did not work

Comment: You still haven't added code! How could we know what is the problem?

Comment: ASD -- I noticed that storing something in a df iteratively is VERY slow. I'd try to store your TextBlobs in a list (or another structure) and then converting that list into a column of a df.

Comment: @qbzenker Thanks a lot. your solution worked. Before it was giving me speeds of 5 its/s now it giving me 600 its/s.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked.

Comment: Going to post it as an answer for ease of reading for future users.

Answer (score 1):

ASD -- I noticed that storing something in a df iteratively is VERY slow. I'd try to store your TextBlobs in a list (or another structure) and then converting that list into a column of a df.