# Faster apply method in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that I'm trying to apply to a dataframe of locations. Specifically, I want to append a new column that contains the 10 closest sites to each site. The following seems to work, but it is excruciatingly slow.

```
def distance(first_lat, first_lon, second_lat, second_lon):
    return ((first_lat - second_lat) ** 2 + (first_lon - second_lon) ** 2) ** 0.5


def load_site_list():
    '''
    This function generates a dataframe with all the available sites
    '''
    url = 'ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-history.csv'
    cols = ["STATION NAME",
            "LAT",
            "LON"]
    df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=False, usecols=cols)
    df = df.dropna(subset=['LAT'])
    df = df.dropna(subset=['LON'])
    df['LAT'] = df['LAT'].astype(float)
    df['LON'] = df['LON'].astype(float)
    return df

sites = load_site_list()
sites['closest'] = ""
for index, row in sites.iterrows():
    sites['dist'] = sites.apply(lambda line: distance(line['LAT'], line['LON'], row['LAT'], row['LON']), axis=1)
    sites.sort_values('dist', inplace=True)
    sites['closest'][index] = sites['STATION NAME'].iloc[1:11].tolist()
```

It appears the first line in the for loop that generates the distances from the current column takes over a second per loop. There's over 10,000 rows in this to loop through...is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using a [KDTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) approach?

Comment: try having your `sites` dataframe as a numpy array (or several arrays) and then creating the dataframe at the end. [see another so answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847238/how-to-increase-the-python-speed-over-loops/43851304#43851304)

Comment: you can use swifter https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your code has a time complexity of O(n^2): In this case, you're computing 30k*30k=900 million distances within an apply function that's in a for loop, i.e. pure Python.

Vector operations in pandas are implemented in C, so you would get a relative speedup if you calculated all the distances in a single vector operation.

If you had enough RAM, you could do a Cartesian join, compute all the pairwise distances, then do a sort, group by, then take the heads, like so:

```
# code to reduce memory usage
sites['site_code'] = pd.Categorical(sites['STATION NAME']).codes
sites['LAT'] = sites.LAT.astype(np.float16)
sites['LON'] = sites.LAT.astype(np.float16)
sites_small = sites[['site_code','LAT','LON']].copy()
sites_small.index = [0]*len(sites_small)

pairs = sites_small.join(sites_small,lsuffix='_x',rsuffix='_y')
pairs['dist'] = (pairs['LAT_x'] - pairs['LAT_y'])**2 + (pairs['LON_x'] - pairs['LON_y'])**2
pairs.sort_values(['STATION NAME_x','dist'], inplace = True) # actually, just sorting by dist is sufficient
pairs.groupby('STATION NAME_x').head(10)
```

Unfortunately, you probably don't have enough RAM: if you encoded the site names into 16-bit integers, and the coordinates into 16-bit floats, you need 12 bytes per row (because you're looking at pairs), plus another 8 bytes for the index (pandas brings these into longints in the join; I don't know how to get around this), which works out to about 20 bytes * 900m rows = 18GB for the final dataframe. It's probably more in practice, and peak memory usage during the operation is higher than this (in particular, the sort will take the longest, and use a ton of memory).

I tried this on my machine: I used about 30GB, gave up waiting on the full sort and sorted a subset where the `dist` was less than 100 instead. Took under 5 minutes, with most of the time being spent on the join.

At the end of the day, you're looking at computing close to a billion calculations; if you want to do this at the speed of C without having to store all the pairwise data (which is the case with a direct method in pandas), you most likely have to write your code in Cython using numpy arrays, and/or with multiprocessing.

The smarter approach is to avoid having to do a billion computations, which involves knowing which distances you don't need to bother computing. This needs some clever logic, but fortunately this is a well-researched topic of k-Nearest Neighbors, which has efficient algorithms specifically designed for problems of this nature:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
data = sites[['LAT','LON']].values
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='auto', metric = 'euclidean').fit(data)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(data)
indices
```

This takes under a second to compute. Recovering the names of the nearest neighbors takes a bit longer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(indices, index = sites['STATION NAME'].values)
df.replace(dict(enumerate(sites['STATION NAME'].values)), inplace = True)
```

(You can actually speed this up considerably by using a `.merge()` method with some stacking/unstacking, but in this case it's slightly trickier because your data contains duplicates.)

Comment: That seems to work quite a bit better. 10 minutes rather than 3 hours. I will be doing some data cleaning. How would you use the merge method if the duplicates are removed?

Comment: `df.stack()` gives you a one-column `Series` of the station indices; turn it into a dataframe and merge it with `pd.DataFrame(enumerate(sites['STATION NAME'].values))`.